Comparative use of 'Le'
I was reading the lyrics of the song "Toda La Noche En La Calle" by Amaral.
The following last two sentences look similar except the use of 'le' in the first one.
Why did they need or choose to use 'le' in the first sentence but not in the second (Que voy ... ) ?
Este es el mundo de los dos
Sin sentido pero tuyo y mío
Este es el mundo de los dos
Qué **le** voy a hacer si mañana nadie sabe
Qué voy a hacer si el futuro está en el aire

and then there is another line in the same song:
Qué **le** voy a hacer si el pasado nunca vuelve
Toda la noche en la calle
Toda la noche en la calle
Cuando llegue el nuevo día
Dormiremos a la orilla del mar

and what does "le" refer to in these sentences? thanks.

Unlike "¿Qué voy a hacer?", which is an ordinary question meaning "What am I going to do?" and usually referring to the near or not so near future, "¿Qué le voy a hacer?" is a more idiomatic, rhetorical question, usually referring to the present. That "le" has no specific referent, and it might refer to the situation: the situation is like this, and there's nothing I can do about it.
Under (12) here we can read:


qué se le va a hacer, qué le voy a hacer,  etc.



Frases con las que se manifiesta resignación ante algo inevitable: «Si aciertas, bien; si no aciertas, qué se le va a hacer» (Tiempo [Esp.] 2.7.1990); «Si mi iniciativa es aceptada, bien. Y si no, qué le voy a hacer» (NProvincia [Arg.] 15.10.1997). Es incorrecto el uso de lo en lugar de le: ⊗‍«En España, los escasos períodos de democracia siempre han coincidido con épocas de crisis. […] Qué lo vamos a hacer» (País [Esp.] 2.1.1981).

(The bolds above are mine)
